# Logstash: 1-hour difference in custom timestamp

Tags: timestamp, logstash, kibana

I am using a custom timestamp field in Logstash (one present in my log file instead of Logstash's `@timestamp` field), and although this timestamp is created and usable in Kibana, there seems to always be a 1-hour difference with the actual timestamp I am fetching.

Here is, for example, actual data from my result source:

> message: **2015-02-02 08:00:36,390** INFO [main] [...]
>
> logtimestamp: "**2015-02-02T07:00:36.390Z**"

I have tried removing and changing the `locale` and `timezone` **date** fields but with no success.

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => "../patterns"
    match => [ "message", "%{LOGTIMESTAMP:logtimestamp}" ]
    tag_on_failure => [ ]
  }
  date {
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "Europe/Paris"
    match => [ "logtimestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    target => "logtimestamp"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are your logs being written in UTC? I'd suggest converting them to another timezone as part of the parse isn't necessarily helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timestamp is stored in Kibana in UTC, irrespectively of what you gave in the `timezone` filter. This timezone identifies the **source**, not the destination timezone.

As a result, your results may appear in Kibana with a time difference of 1 hour. This is because Paris is one hour ahead of UTC on most days. So, the behaviour is fully intended.

There is an issue open to allow the disply of @timestamp in local time: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/95 , which was closed a while back and marked as implemented. It's in the user settings in Kibana.

Comment: Timezone support is now available as of [Kibana 4.3](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1600) that's been released on Nov 24th, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the next order on logstash.conf

```
date {
    match => [ "my_date" , "ISO8601" ]
    timezone => "America/Mexico_City"
    target => "my_date"
}
```

Att: hec0160